polynomial $p(x) + C$ has only simple root for $C$ large enough
Let $p(x) = a^n x^n + ... + a_1 x + a_0$ be a polynomial with real coefficients.
Let $C > 0$. Then if $C$ is large enough then it's easy to see that $p(x) + C$ has only simple real roots.
Is there a way to make this $C$ explicit in terms of $(a_n, ..., a_0)$? i.e.
Is it possible to say if  $C > F(a_n, ..., a_0)$ then $p(x) + C$ only has simple root
where $F$ is some expression. Thank you
clarification: I meant, if $p(x) + C$ does have a real root then it is simple.  my apologies for the confusion.

"Let $p(x) = a^n x^n + ... + a_1 x + a_0$ be a polynomial with real coefficients.
Let $C > 0$. Then if $C$ is large enough then it's easy to see that $p(x) + C$ has only simple real roots." -- This is not true. Take $x^2+1$; $x^2+1+C$ will never have real roots (simple or otherwise) for any $C>0$.

@PrincessEev It depends how you parse "has only simple real roots". The only real roots of $x^2+1$ are simple (vacuously).

I wonder how ambitious you are about the expression F. Can you give a hint about qualities you might be satisfied with?

for now I was thinking about anything available, so nothing ambitious

I would interprete the  formulation "has only simple real roots" that all the roots of the function are real and simple. Apparently , something very different is meant. Please formulate clearly what you want.

A root $r$ is of $p(x)+C$ is not simple if $p(r)+C=0$ and $p'(r)=0.$ Let $r_1,\ldots, r_{n-1}$ be the roots  of $p'(x).$   The roots are repeated according to their multiplicity. Let $C=\max_{1\le k\le n-1}|p(r_k)| +1.$ Then $p(x)+C$ does not vanish at $r_k$ for any $k.$ Thus any, possibly complex, root  of $p(x)$ is simple. In particular any real root of $p(x)+C$ is simple. As has been observed in the comments $p(x)+C$ may not admit real roots whatsoever.
It is possible to estimate the absolute value of the roots of $p'(x)$ by a positive constant $m,$ in terms of $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^n.$  Indeed if $|r|\ge 1$ is a root  then
$$n|a_n||r|^{n-1}\le (n-1)\max_{1\le k\le n-1}k|a_k||r|^{k-1}\\ \le (n-1)^2r^{n-2}\max_{1\le k\le n-1}|a_k|$$
Hence $$|r| \le {(n-1)^2\over n|a_n|}\max_{1\le k\le n-1}|a_k|=:m_0$$ We can take $m=m_0+1.$
Then $$|p(r_k)|\le \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|m^k$$
